# Add WCF RESTful service as application to classic ASP website

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

Well. We have a legacy classic asp website running on IIS 8.5 on windows server 2012. Both http and https protocols are enabled for the website. Recently I developed a standalone WCF web service and added it as Application to our website (with different application pool). 
Now WCF works fine with http protocol but not with https. Service.svc loads normally with https, but for all requests returns 400

this is my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="1000"/>
  </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel> 
    <services>
      <service name="KATProductFilter.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="mycorp.Callback.SecPayServiceBehavior">
         <endpoint address=""
                   binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportBinding" 
                   contract="KATProductFilter.IService1"/>      
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="mycorp.Callback.SecPayServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransportBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">  
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
            <add prefix="https://www.knivesandtools.nl/filterssl"/> 
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
    </serviceHostingEnvironment> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mike, I've used this link as reference and worked fine to me, maybe it can help you too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Endpoint's binding must be webHttpBinding and it MUST have both bindingConfiguration and behaviorConfiguration as follow.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="test">
            <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="katproductfilter_behavior">
        <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
    <service name="KATProductFilter.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="test">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="KATProductFilter.IService1" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="katproductfilter_behavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
```

P.S Ricardo thanks for link.